# Java & Android: Get Router's MAC Address/ip.vX adress

Tags: java, android, network-programming

The Problem:
There are several router's onsite and I want to specify which router I am connected to. My initial thought was to get the ROUTER'S (not my device's) Mac Address which determines specifically that router.

It doesn't have to be MAC Address the point is to determine which router I am connect to. Note that all routers are under the same SSID and when I walk from A to C wing the connection never stops.

It will be used in a Android application but if we have a solution in Java that can be implemented in Android too.

Comment: You're probably looking for the address of the default gateway. The remote mac address might only give you the physical address of the access point, not the router.

Comment: That's enough actually if I can distinguish the routers from each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getBSSID()` from `WifiInfo` Class.

It will return you the MAC Address of the access point you're connected to.

More details at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo#getBSSID()